# Show that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{d}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a subfield of $\mathbb C$. Then if $k, \sqrt{d}  \in S$, then $k \sqrt{d} \in S$ since $S$ is closed under $ *$. Also, if $j \in S$, then $j + k \sqrt{d} \in S$ since $S$ is closed under $+$. So, $S = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$. Since $0 + 1 \sqrt{d}$ and $a + 0 \sqrt{d} \in S$, then $\mathbb Q$ and $ \sqrt{d} \in S$ so that $S$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt d$

It's a rewrite of [this little proof here](http://s12.postimg.org/f7rbkh2f1/fgdfg.png).

Trying to see if I understand the given example correctly. What part of my rewrite needs to be fixed to correct my understanding? Thanks.

Comment: Notice that the title, as it stands, proposes to show something which is false. Please avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, I think you mean "smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing $\sqrt d$". The smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your definitions and assumptions.  Isn't Q the smallest subfield of C?  If you mean the smallest subfield with $\sqrt{d}$ you've shown $Q(\sqrt{d} \subset S$ but I don't see that you've shown $S \subset of Q(\sqrt d)$.  What if $\sqrt 2, \sqrt 5 \in S$?  Then $S \not \subset Q(\sqrt 5)$.  And when you say $k, j \in S$ are you assuming j and k are rationals.

Comment: @fleablood, Yes I do mean smallest subfield with $\sqrt{d}$ and yes $j, k \in \mathbb Q$. Can you elaborate what author said in the link I provided a little? I mean exactly what assumptions is he proving and is my rewrite kind of close to what he is saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  If you are really just trying to rewrite the the example given, don't refer to the subfield S.  That's a third field and there is nothing in your writing that explains any relation between $S$ and $\mathbb Q$.

So to start with $\mathbb Q$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$.  Now we know a few things about $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb C$ that we really aren't allowed to assume in the the general case of $F$ being a subfield of $K$.

We know for instance that $\mathbb Q \ne \mathbb C$.  We don't know $F \ne K$.  We know that $\mathbb Q$ is the smallest subfield of $C$.  We don't know that $F$ is the smallest subfield of $K$.   We know that if $\alpha \in \mathbb C; \alpha \not \in \mathbb Q$ that $\mathbb Q \subsetneq \mathbb Q(\alpha) \subsetneq \mathbb C$.  If $\alpha \in K; \alpha \not \in F$ we know $F \subsetneq F(\alpha)$ and we know $F(\alpha) \subset K$ but we don't know $F(\alpha) \ne K$.

So... the statement is if $\alpha \in K$ then $F(\alpha)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ that both contains $F$ as a subfield, and contains $\alpha$ as an element.  i.e. $F \subset F(\alpha) \subset K$. and there is no other subfield *that contains $\alpha$* "between" $F$ and $F(\alpha)$.  Note.  There can be *many* subfields smaller than F that do *not* contain $\alpha$ and there may be many subfields "between" $F(\alpha)$ and $K$.  But there aren't any subfields between $F$ and $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\alpha)$ is the smallest that contains $\alpha$ *AND* contains $F$ as a subfield.  There may or may not be smaller subfields of $K$ that contain $\alpha$ but which do *not* contain $F$.

Also note:  No-one ever said $\alpha \not \in F$.  If $\alpha \in F$ then $F(\alpha) = F$.  And it is (trivially) the smallest subfield of $K$ that contains $F$ (and $\alpha$).

...

Okay....  So let's take $\sqrt{d} \in \mathbb C$.  There are two possibilities.

I)  $\sqrt{d} \in \mathbb Q$.  If so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d}) = \mathbb Q$.  $\mathbb Q$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ that *contains $\mathbb Q$ as a subfield* and also contains $\sqrt{d}$.

II) $\sqrt{d} \not \in \mathbb Q$.  If so $\mathbb Q \subsetneq \mathbb Q(\sqrt{d}) \subsetneq \mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ that contains $\mathbb Q$ as a subfield and also contains $\sqrt{d}$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much.